# How to create redirection specific routes in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing

In my project, whenever a user enters a URL like `/applyLeave`, if the user is not logged in then I am redirecting the user to the `/login` page. Now again when the user successfully login to the website, I am again redirecting the user to the original URL(i.e. `/applyLeave`). So my question is that how to create a URL like `/login?redirectTo=applyLeave` while redirecting from `/login` to `/applyLeave`?

Comment: You can just simply add it to the url string and then get the query parameter inside the login component

Comment: Hi @FireFighter. Can you elaborate? I am not getting exactly what you are saying.

Comment: @starlordhh you are using react router isn't it?

Comment: yes @DeepakSharma